# What does ぉ character mean in のぉ?

Tags: translation, sentence-final-particles, nouns

Can somebody explain the purpose of ぉ character in the end of the following sentence?

What part of speech can be assigned to ぉ ?

Can the ending の be glued up with ぉ?

> アドビにうまいことやられた**のぉ**。

Comment: Another link for 「のう」: [大辞林's entry for のう](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%AE%E3%81%86&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=1&pagenum=1&index=115248800000)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to just be an emphatic, stylistic lengthening of the `の` preceding it.

Answer (score 15):

The のぉ is what we normally write as 「[のう](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%86-596155)」, one of the sentence ending particles (終助詞).

I think it sounds rather archaic, now *we think* it's only used by older people (but I doubt it's actually used daily anymore... I think we only see it in fictional works eg anime, manga, dramas, novels etc.), and younger people don't use it in "normal" conversation. I think it's probably the archaic equivalent for modern ね/ねえ/ねぇ or maybe な/なあ.

It has a different intonation from the sentence ending particle [の (終助詞)](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AE-596099).

> 「のう」⇒「やられた↗[のう]{HL}↘。(The subject is probably the hearer.)」
> 「の」⇒「どうした↘[の～]{LH}↗？(The subject is the hearer.)」--「やられた↘[の～]{LL}↘。(The subject is the speaker.)」