# The のう ending in this sentence

Tags: translation, particles, syntax

> 当時を知る者があれを見て、本人とは思わないだろうから**のう**

The sentence is taken from a visual novel. I am wondering what the ending "のう" means in this context. I've tried searching it but the only thing people were asking was "のいう" and I am not sure if that is the same thing.

Comment: Is the speaker old?  I read it as being [this のう](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12106/1478).

Comment: @snailboat you're spot on! Thanks for the link, I got it.